# Microsoft Teams Bot Link Unfurling - on mobile

Tags: mobile, botframework, microsoft-teams

There is no link unfurling in the teams mobile app on iOS.

We wrote a MS Teams link unfurling bot - which works fine. The Teams App (Bot) is installed company wide via the Teams Admin.
If we post a Link in the Teams App (Web/Desktop) the link unfurling works as expected.
But if we post the link on the Teams mobile App (iOS/Android) there is no link unfurling. Anything we need to do to enable link unfurling in the mobile app or is it not supported?

Comment: Link unfurling is supported only for links that don't require authentication in mobile.

Comment: Is that a restriction for the mobile client? The link unfurling works perfectly on desktop and in the browser.

Comment: Yes, please check this note https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling?tabs=desktop%2Cjson%2Cadvantages#:~:text=For%20mobile%20client%2C%20link%20unfurling%20is%20supported%20only%20for%20links%20that%20don%27t%20require%20authentication. We are also checking this internally.

Comment: @Mehana-MSFT do you know why this restriction is in place? The link is sent to our bots backend where we generate the card - it makes not difference if the link needs a login or not. Or is it possible that custom link unfurling bots are not implemented in the mobile client and only the "normal" link unfurling for links without authentication works?